# How to load content into a WebView by touching a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I Have a collection of views in a view controller. by touching one of those views I would like to load specific data, for ex. a webpage into a web view that is on the same view controller

How would you accomplish that?

Thank you in advance

Here is my code with does not want to work:

```
    UIView *categoryTitle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 166 * counter
                                                                     , 500, 20)];

    UILabel *categoryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 200, 20)];

    [categoryLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSMutableArray *allCurrentNews = [[News alloc] allNewsFromCategory:cat.CategoryId];

    categoryLabel.text = cat.Name;
    categoryLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [categoryTitle addSubview:categoryLabel];

    UIColor *myblack = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.14 green:0.14 blue:0.14 alpha:1];
    UIColor *ligheterBlac = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.227 green:0.22 blue:0.22 alpha:1];
    [categoryTitle setBackgroundColor:myblack];

    UIScrollView *tempScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 166 * counter, 500, 166)];

    UIColor *tempcolor = ligheterBlac; 
    tempScroll.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.34 green:0.34 blue:0.34 alpha:1].CGColor;
    tempScroll.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    int countnews = 0;

    for (News *news in allCurrentNews)
    {
        UIView *newsContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160 * countnews, 30, 156, 126)];
        newsContainer.tag = countnews + 1;
        [newsContainer addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

        //newsContainer.NewsId = news.NewsId;
        LazyImageView *image = [[LazyImageView alloc] initWithURl:[NSURL URLWithString:news.Thumbnail]];
        image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 156, 96);
        UILabel *newsTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 96, 156, 30)];
        newsTitle.backgroundColor = myblack;
        newsTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
        newsTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
        newsTitle.text = news.Title;
        newsTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        newsTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        newsContainer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.34 green:0.34 blue:0.34 alpha:1].CGColor;
        newsContainer.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

        [newsContainer addSubview:image];
        [newsContainer addSubview:newsTitle];

        countnews ++;
        [tempScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(allCurrentNews.count * 156, 96)];
        [tempScroll addSubview:newsContainer];
        //[image release];
    }

    [tempScroll setBackgroundColor: tempcolor];

    [categories addSubview:tempScroll];
    [categories addSubview:categoryTitle];
    [tempcolor release];
    [tempScroll release];
    counter ++;
}

self.detailsView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.detailsView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-10, 5);
self.detailsView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.detailsView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;

[self.view addSubview:categories];
[self.view addSubview:_detailsView];
[self.view addSubview:MainSubTitle];
[self.view addSubview:MainTitle];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:selector(processTap:)];
  UIView *targetView = //assign the view you need
  targetView.tag = 5;
  [targetView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

- (void)processTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  UIView *view = recognizer.view;
  if (view.tag == 5) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I get use of undeclared identifier "processTap"
and "implicit declaration of function selector is invalid in c99"

Comment: Well it's pretty basic stuff. Add this line - (void)processTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer; to your .h file or to private extension in the .m file.

Comment: I did everything but it still does not get called

Comment: So do you receive a compiler error or the method simply does not gets called? Check .userInteractionEnabled property of the UIView if that's the case

Comment: it doesn't get called, i have a lot of other views added within a for loop, as soon as i remove those from the code, everything runs fine. I have no clue what is interfering with the gesture recognizer

Comment: One of the most important properties of UIView - userInteractionEnabled is set to NO by default if UIView object is being created programmatically. Set it to YES in a loop for each view and that might solve your problem. Just don't add the recognizer to views in the loop or you'll have unexpected results, like the one you're having now. Also the problem might be with that some of the views that are on top of your target view in subview hierarchy also have their recognizers and they will intercept the touch event and process it. Maybe drop some code with how you're creating those views

Comment: You seem to be totally right, setting recognizers in a loop is causing a problem, but what is a workaround, how can i set recognizers to those views?

Comment: Right now you're setting the same recognizer to all of the views, it just gets removed from the previous one and transferred onto the new one. Create recognizers in the loop and everything will work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are my saver !